# How can I change the default html / php landings page to another one if I clicked on a link

Tags: php, html, cookies

I want to change the landings page if i click on a button or link

So for example I have two pages: page-1 and page-2.

If i click on link-2 the default landings page get changed from page-1 to page-2 and if I click on link-1 the default landings page get changed from page-2 to page-1.

If i leave the website and come back i want that the default landings page is still the same as it was set last time.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by setting a cookie like this:

```
<?php

if($_GET['landingpage']) setcookie("landingpage", $_GET['landingpage'], time()+3600);

if($_COOKIE["landingpage"] == 1) {
  echo "landingpage 1";
}

if($_COOKIE["landingpage"] == 2) {
  echo "landingpage 2";
}

if(!$_COOKIE["landingpage"]) echo "default page";

?>

<a href="?landingpage=1">landingpage1</a>
<a href="?landingpage=2">landingpage2</a>
```

Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php for more info on expiration, etc.

Also beware: Not all users allow setting cookies.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a PHP server that can store data (I'm assuming this because of the PHP tag), then you would handle it like this:

1. When the user hits your landing page, pull their landing page preference from your PHP data store and use that to determine what page they hit.
2. If the user clicks your link, you need to send that information back to the PHP server so that it can store their preferences, likely via an API call.

This is very high level, because both of these tasks tend to have a lot of different ways. I'd recommend trying to make this work, then asking specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? Just set a cookie or local storage.. done ;-)

Comment: I suppose that would work as well. I was assuming the desire was to have the landing page stay the same across browsers or if the same user opened the page on another machine, but I think you're right, that's overcomplicating things.